# Unable to use rewrite and subst in Syslog-ng

Tags: logging, syslog, logstash, syslog-ng

When I write my logs without adding my substitution I am able to write just fine however since I am building upon a central logging server I need to add the host name from the source log to the existing message that is being processed.  I intend of having the substitution be something to this effect.

```
- - [
```

with

```
$HOST [
```

Where $HOST is the universal macro for a hostname.

When I run the following removes my entire line when I run the substitution.  Does anyone have any idea what I am doing wrong with my regex?  The docs said that I needed to use [ within single quotes to make this special character a literal.

```
rewrite r_addhostname{
  subst('- - \[', '$HOST \[', value("MESSAGE"));
};
```

Thanks in advance, Cole

Comment: Have you tried using the "keep-hostname" option in your destination?

Comment: I haven't however I simply added $HOST to my template to accomplish something similar.  Then theoretically parse against that after it is pulled from a key->store system like redis.   I may take a different route anyways.  Just dump it to a UDP port and directly off of UDP on a different logstash machine.

Comment: We have set up Intel Nuc boxes in client offices to collect syslog messages from LAN devices and forward them to a cloud server through a TLS tunnel.  In the /etc/syslog-ng/conf.d folder, I'll create a tls.conf file with "keep-hostname();" in the 'destination d_tls' line, and it works like a champ.